# Prison Architect: Campaign Level 3 won't advance

Tags: prison-architect

I am playing campaign level 3 in Prison Architect. I've completed everything in the todo list - it's empty. I saw the cutscene where the CEO tells Benedict that each incarcerated prisoner is worth 73K per year. I don't know what to do to advance to the next cutscene. All of the following objectives have been completed:

- Hire guards and deploy them to the recaptured zones
- (OPTIONAL) Tend to the medical needs of your prison
- (Optional) Build an Infirmary and treat the wounded
- (Optional) Build a Morgue and collect the dead
- Recapture the Gen-Pop wing (central)
- Recapture the Special wing (west)
- Recapture the Max-Sec wing (south)
- Bring the fire under control

What do I need to do to advance?

Comment: There should be a polaroid in the top-right I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug in the game caused by ignoring the incoming call from Benedict until after suppressing the riot. To avoid this bug, be sure to answer the call from Benedict before completely suppressing the riot. The riot suppression seems to trigger the final cut-scene.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bring guards into the zone with the hostages

> and then there's a Shootout, which results in the hostage being killed.

After that the polaroid should appear (you may have to Zoom in, since the polaroid has the same colour of the floor and is hard to see)